# Graphing the Thomae Function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could someone please give me guidance on how to plot this special function? I honestly have no idea where even to start (I've never actually done a `\tikzpicture` from scratch).

```
\[
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
    0, &x \ \text{irrational}\\
    \frac{1}{q}, &x = \frac{p}{q} \  \text{in lowest form}\\[10pt]
    \end{array}\right\}
```

]

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a cartoon as your this screen shot?AFAIK there are infinitely many rational numbers in the interval [0,1] so drawing the dots requires the specification of a cut-off for `q`, I think.

Comment: This is Thomae's function, sometimes called the popcorn function. It is built into the `pst-func` package, located [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf) on CTAN. See page 66.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a proposal. Of course, this is just a cartoon because I had to cut off `q`, as is done in your screen shot.

**EDIT**: In my previous version there was a huge conceptual flaw. Big big thanks to Peter Grill for bringing it to my attention!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\draw [-stealth] (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0);
\draw [-stealth] (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.6);
\foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{\ifnum\X=1
\else
\draw (0.02,1/\X) -- (-0.02,1/\X) node[left,xshift={(-(1+pow(-1,\X)))*3pt}]{$\frac{1}{\X}$};
\fi
}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Ymax using {int(\X-1)}]in {25,24,...,2}
{\foreach \Y in {1,...,\Ymax}
 {\ifnum\X<6
 \draw (\Y/\X,0.02) -- (\Y/\X,-0.02) node[below,fill=white]{$\frac{\Y}{\X}$};
 \else
 \draw[ultra thin] (\Y/\X,0.01) -- (\Y/\X,-0.01);
 \fi
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TST}{gcd(\X,\Y)}
 \ifnum\TST=1
 \fill ({\Y/\X},1/\X) circle(0.2pt); 
 \fi
 }
}
\foreach \X in {0,1,...,80}
{\fill (\X/80,0) circle(0.2pt); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer are excellent. Have you take the "virus" of the best users of LaTeX? :-):-). +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Such a virus does not exist and I am certainly not the best user of LaTeX.

Comment: I hope you understand my line. I was joking; you're a very good, useless person to deny it.

Comment: How would you suggest putting in dots on the x-axis? As shown in the screenshot

Comment: @MiguelCumming-Romo Just add `\foreach \X in {0,1,...,80}
    {\fill (\X/80,0) circle(0.2pt); }` (you may replace `80` by some other number) as I did in my second example. To make the numbers irrational, you could shift the circles by a tiny irrational amount, but in the end none of the computer-generated numbers are irrational).

Comment: Sorry! Last question: How do I x-shift  `\foreach \X in {0,1,...,80} {\fill (\X/80,0) circle(0.2pt);`

Comment: @MiguelCumming-Romo You could just do `\foreach \X in {0,1,...,80}
{\fill (\X/80+pi/700,0) circle(0.2pt); }`.

Comment: Are the multiple points above x=1/2 correct? They don't appear in the OP's question, the other solution and Wikipedia.  Similar issue at other rational points.

Comment: @PeterGrill Good point! You're right! Will fix it asap.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sagetex` solution using the computer algebra system, SAGE, to do the computations.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
xvalue = []
yvalue = []
for q in range(1,101):
    for p in range(1,q):
        xvalue += [(p*1.0/q*1.).n(digits=2)]
        yvalue += [(1/(q/gcd(p,q))).n(digits=2)]
output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}["
output += r"title={Thomae's function},"
output += r"xlabel=$x$,"
output += r"ylabel=$f(x)$,"
output += r"]"
output += r"\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=.5pt}] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(xvalue)):
    output += r"(%s, %s)"%(xvalue[i],yvalue[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The result running in [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is shown below:
[image]

By changing the value of q from 101 to something more, you'll get more points. SAGE is not part of the LaTeX distribution, so you would need to install it on your computer or, to avoid that, get a free Cocalc account. The documentation for SAGE is [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/index.html) and the documentation for `sagetex` is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) on CTAN. The SAGE programming involves a mixture of SAGE commands mixed into Python code. If your work involves mathematics, then this is a very convenient package to learn.