# How can I improve the drawing of Thomae's function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I 'm trying to draw *Thomae's function* (in black). I want the plot below.

[image]

I used marmot's code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461603/graphing-the-thomae-function).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\draw [-stealth] (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0);
\draw [-stealth] (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.6);
\foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{\ifnum\X=1
\else
\draw (0.02,1/\X) -- (-0.02,1/\X) node[left,xshift={(-(1+pow(-1,\X)))*3pt}]{$\frac{1}{\X}$};
\fi
}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Ymax using {int(\X-1)}]in {25,24,...,2}
{\foreach \Y in {1,...,\Ymax}
 {\ifnum\X<6
 \draw (\Y/\X,0.02) -- (\Y/\X,-0.02) node[below,fill=white]{$\frac{\Y}{\X}$};
 \else
 \draw[ultra thin] (\Y/\X,0.01) -- (\Y/\X,-0.01);
 \fi
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TST}{gcd(\X,\Y)}
 \ifnum\TST=1
 \fill ({\Y/\X},1/\X) circle(0.2pt); 
 \fi
 }
}
\foreach \X in {0,1,...,80}
{\fill (\X/80,0) circle(0.2pt); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I have **3 problems**:

1. I prefer the image to have **more details**, as the one I saw you.
2. I **don't want the space between** *x-dots* and *upper-dots*.

[image]

3. If I use this code, **I get an other (flat) image**, than this I expected.

[image]

- Is there any solutions for **1** and **2**?
- If it's not, what should I do with **3**?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Could you consider using `pstricks`? The `pst-func`  package has a predefined `\psThomae` command, which  plots the function.

Comment: @Bernard , thanks for your answer! I have never used `pstricks`, but I 'll try it!

Comment: You have discovered a bug in the update of Ti*k*Z, thanks for spotting it. `gcd` does no longer work properly, try e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{gcd(4,9)}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}`. I believe I know who made this change, and will try to fix it asap.

Comment: It has been reported officially: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/706

Comment: @marmot , thanks for your answer! I didn't understand how to use your code (`\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} \begin{document} \pgfmathparse{gcd(4,9)}\pgfmathresult \end{document}`). Should I change something of the first code?

Comment: If you compile with `pdflatex`, load also  `auto-pst-pdf` (pdflatex doesn't understand the calculations of the postscript language) to have a shorter compilation chain, or compile with `xelatex`` .

Comment: The bug has been resolved by Henri Menke, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/706, where you can find a temporary fix. With this fix decreasing the gap is as simple as increasing upper bound of the loop domain, e.g. `\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Ymax using {int(\X-1)}]in {55,54,...,2}`.

Comment: @marmot excellent!!! Thank's for your time! Problem solved!

Comment: You're welcome! And sorry for the bug, and thanks for spotting it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the bug was corrected in the current version ...